# Por que o ponteiro não incrementa o valor?

Tags: c, ponteiro, operadores

Aqui era para incrementar o valor da variável, porém não funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *p, x = 10;

    p = &x;
    *p = (*p)++;
    printf("%d \n", *p);

    return 0;
}
```

Resultado: 10

Comment: O problema é o seu operador de incremento depois da variável. Se você fizer *p = ++(*p); obterá o resultado esperado.

Comment: Teste simples: x = 3;
y = ++x;
// Neste ponto x contem 4 e y contem 4

x = 3;
y = x++;
// Neste ponto x contem 4 e y contem 3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isto produz um comportamento indefinido. O operador de incremento já é um operador de atribuição. Basta deixá-lo sozinho que tudo funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *p, x = 10;
    p = &x;
    (*p)++;
    printf("%d \n", *p);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2A6Aaf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tzynilgz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Increment.c).

Comment: Onde ocorre o comportamento indefinido?

Comment: Na linha que eu alterei `*p = (*p)++;`.

Comment: "Onde" foi modo de falar, rsrs. Qual é a explicação para o comportamento indefinido? Qual regra foi quebrada, digamos assim.

Comment: Não sei dizer exatamente nesse caso. Até onde eu sei a especificação não diz nada sobre (exatamente) isso. Talvez algo relacionado a isto: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point. Talvez algo assim ajude explicar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/949508/221800

Comment: Imaginei algo relacionado a isso, mas perguntei pra ver se você explicaria didaticamente, porque não entendo nada sobre os _sequence points_ (só sei que existem). Se descobrir mais detalhes, não se esqueça de editar. :)

Comment: Também não tenho conhecimento profundo sobre eles. Faz tempo que me prometo dar uma estudada, mas sempre fica pra depois.

Comment: Isso não funciona pois está usando o operador `++` como pós incremento. Tanto que se alterar a linha `*p = (*p)++;` para `*p = ++(*p);` vai retornar o resultado esperado. Mas porque isso acontece? o operador de pós incremento é o último a ser executado. A váriável até é incrementada, mas o valor é perdido pois o operador `=` foi usado, pegando assim o valor antes do incremento.

Comment: Eu fiquei confuso com esse último comentário do @Pilati, então é UB ou não? Pela explicação que ele deu parece ser definido. Ou é UB por que a especificação não determina nada sobre a ordem de avaliação (de modo que o comportamento que ele explicou apenas um dos possíveis). É isso?

Comment: É UB, não há definição do que deve ocorrer quando há duas atribuições. Indefinido não quer dizer aleatório, apenas diz que você não pode contar com isso, mesmo que ocorra todas as vezes.

Answer (score 2):

`*p = (*p)++;` não gera comportamento indefinido, como o @Maniero disse. Este é um comando com comportamento perfeitamente entendível e previsível. O problema aqui é que o comando `(*p)++`, em si, já incrementa o valor contido em `x`.

Observe o código abaixo:

```
int x = 0;
int *p = &x;
```

Aqui, o computador irá criar duas "caixinhas" na memória.

- Uma "caixinha" para guardar um inteiro, chamada x.
- E outra "caixinha" para guardar o **endereço** de um inteiro, chamada p

em outras palavras:

Uma variável do tipo `int` armazena um inteiro.

Uma variável do tipo `int*` armazena um **endereço** de um inteiro.

Agora suponha que `x` esteja no endereço `0x000000`
e que `p` esteja em `0x111111`

O comando `(p)` nos retorna o **endereço** de x na memória, ou seja, `0x000000`

O comando `(*p)` nos retorna o **valor** contido no endereço `0x000000`, ou seja, `0`.

Quando você faz `*p = (*p)++;` você esta pedindo ao processador que faça o seguinte:

```
*p = (*    p   )++;

 ^    ^    ^    ^

 4    2    1    3
```

1. Pegue o **endereço** armazenado por `p` (`0x000000`)
2. Acesse o **valor** deste endereço (`0`)
3. **Incremente** esse **valor** (`0` -> `1`). Agora `x = 1`.
4. Atribua o novo **valor** (`1`) à `p`.

Na etapa 4 que a coisa fica séria. Aqui você está trocando o **conteúdo** de `p`, que era `0x000000`, para `0x00001`, que é `1` em `hexadecimal`. Fazendo isso, `p` pára de apontar para x, e começa a apontar para um "endereço alheio". O **enderço** de x permanece `0X000000`, mas o seu conteúdo agora é `1`. O endereço de `p` também permanece o mesmo `0x111111` mas o seu **valor**, que antes era `0x000000` (endereço de x), agora passa a ser (`0x000001`).

O código

```
int *p, x = 0;
p = &x;
*p = (*p)++;
```

pode ser reescrito como:

```
int x = 0;
int *p = 0x000000;

x = 1;
p = 0x00001;
```

assumindo que o **endereço** de `x` seja `0x000000`

Comment: Me parece um caso de _comportamento indefinido_ sim. Teria como indicar **na especificação da linguagem** algo que afirme que o momento da ocorrência do pós-incremento em relação à atribuição aconteça na ordem que explicação descreve?